# How to fix the nginx package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, nginx

I have installed nginx .

```
dpkg -l nginx
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend 
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  nginx          1.6.2-5      all          small, powerful, scalable web/pro
```

Everytime i go to install other package ,the error info displayed.

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-full' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

How to fix it ,not to let the info displayed again when to install other package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing serious. Reinstall the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nginx-full nginx-common
```

---

*Example*

After deleting `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mc.list` via

```
sudo rm sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mc.list
```

I get the followning

```
% sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp-gmic numix-icon-theme
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5.130 kB of archives.
After this operation, 106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu/ vivid/main gimp-gmic amd64 1:1.6.5.2-0v0~ppa~edge [1.828 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main numix-icon-theme all 0.3+524~201509050731~ubuntu15.04.1 [3.302 kB]
Fetched 5.130 kB in 4s (1.172 kB/s)           
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Fixed with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mc
```

Comment: something strage happen when to reintall nginx.

Comment: service nignx  start
Failed to start nignx.service: Unit nignx.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: what is the matter with my nginx?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a completely different question **;)** Therefore [ask here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libssh2-1:amd64 (1.5.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up mc-data (3:4.8.15-2) ...
Setting up mc (3:4.8.15-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
```

I keep getting errors....

Comment: Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Şub 06 12:36:40 mapeg systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1